# I cannot get javascript to function properly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on this small project for college. I need to make and interactive page using html/css/javascript. The problem is, my javascript doesn't work, I've tried using lecturers script that is meant to work 100%, but even then it doesn't. I checked my browser settings, and made sure that javascript is allowed. Maybe someone can see what the problem is.

I'm currently trying to make a slider for this page and connect it to a .js file. I used same code our lecturer showed. Slider is there, but it is not displaying the value for me. Here's my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en-IE">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Disney Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="flex-box">
                <div>
                    <form action="" onsubmit="return false;">
                        <label>How much do you like Disney?:</label>
                        <p>
                            0<input type="range" min="0" max="10" id="likeDisney">10<span id="opinion"></span>
                        </p>
                    </form>
                    <img src="images/Donald_Duck.jpg" alt="Donalt_Duck">
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("likeDisney").onchange= slide;
function slide()
{
    var likedisney = document.getElementById("likeDisney").value;
    if (likedisney>6) {
        document.getElementById("opinion").innerHTML="Love it!";
        }
        else if (likedisney>4) {
            document.getElementById("opinion").innerHTML="Like it!";
        }
    else {
        document.getElementById("opinion").innerHTML="Not a fan of Disney";
        }
}
```

Comment: Try doing this `var likedisney = Number(document.getElementById("likeDisney").value)`

Comment: Nothing really changed. Still doesn't display value

Comment: You need to close the `head` tag. your closing head tag does not have and `/`

Comment: Fixed head closing tag, but it's still the same :/